# Fetching an array of data with .map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

Currently I'm trying to move API data fetching from child component to parent component. So i wanted to do some sort of mapping to do many fetches at once and save the data to an array, but I'm really new to async JS and I'm struggling with it. My function looks like this right now:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const result = await newArray.map((item, index) =>
        axios.get(`http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index + 1}`)
      );
      setDataNew(result);
      console.log(dataNew);
    })();
  }, []);
```

newArray is just a created array, to map all 151 pokemons. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, No need for the nested immediately invoked function, all that would do is swallow the return value.

Secondly, your awaiting on an array of promises, but the array is not a promise. You should wrap the array of promises in a `Promise.all` call in order to wait on each individual promise in the array.

```
useEffect(async () => {
      const result = await Promise.all(newArray.map((item, index) =>
        axios.get(`http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index + 1}`)
      )); // result will be an array of values (not promises)
      setDataNew(result);
      console.log(dataNew);
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you, but it seems I'm getting an empty array now.

Comment: is `newArray` empty? is `setDataNew` actually setting `dataNew`? is `result` also empty?

Comment: newArray is filled with 0's, because I initialized it with them. Well, result is properly filled with data. dataNew is still empty but I have a feeling that console lies to me. I'll work with it again tomorrow, thank you.

Comment: sounds like a problem in `setDataNew`. You'll have to include the code for that if u'd like feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried something to make this work, but no luck.
Currently my code looks like this:

```js
  const [dataNew, setDataNew] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const result = await Promise.all(
        newArray.map((item, index) =>
          axios.get(`http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${index + 1}`)
        )
      );
      setDataNew(result);
      console.log(result);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

And console.logging result gives me an array of 151 undefined. How can I make it work? @junvar